# TeXstudio and RStudio do not see tufte-book.cls but TeXshop does

Tags: texstudio, texshop, rstudio, tufte-book

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\title{title}
\author{me}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

TeXstudio and Rstudio complain

> File `tufte-book.cls' not found

**TeXstudio log**

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2022/dev) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.8.11)  12 AUG 2021 14:55
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**tufteTry1.tex
(./tufteTry1.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-07-12>

! LaTeX Error: File `tufte-book.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.2 ^^M
       
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 23 strings out of 480502
 501 string characters out of 5898668
 286634 words of memory out of 5000000
 17807 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 403430 words of font info for 27 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 19i,0n,29p,71b,17s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!`
```

**TeXshop log**

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2022/dev) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.8.12)  12 AUG 2021 09:43
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**tufteTry.tex
(./tufteTry.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-07-12>
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tufte-latex/tufte-book.cls
Document Class: tufte-book 2015/06/21 v3.5.2 Tufte-book class
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tufte-latex/tufte-common.def
File: tufte-common.def 2015/06/21 v3.5.2 Common code for the Tufte-LaTeX styles


(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2020/11/20 v2.8 package option processing (HA)

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks16
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks17

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count182
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xifthen/xifthen.sty
Package: xifthen 2015/11/05 v1.4.0 Extended ifthen features

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty
Package: calc 2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count183
\calc@Bcount=\count184
\calc@Adimen=\dimen138
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen139
\calc@Askip=\skip47
\calc@Bskip=\skip48
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count185
\calc@Cskip=\skip49
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2020/11/24 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifmtarg/ifmtarg.sty
Package: ifmtarg 2018/04/16 v1.2b check for an empty argument
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hardwrap/hardwrap.sty
Package: hardwrap 2011/02/12 v0.2 Hard wrap messages

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifplatform/ifplatform.sty
Package: ifplatform 2017/10/13 v0.4a Testing for the operating system

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty
Package: shellesc 2019/11/08 v1.0c unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
Package shellesc Info: Restricted shell escape enabled on input line 77.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/catchfile/catchfile.sty
Package: catchfile 2019/12/09 v1.8 Catch the contents of a file (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)

Package ifplatform Warning: 
    shell escape is disabled, so I can only detect \ifwindows.

) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2019/10/25 v0.7 ifxetex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
\hw@charcount=\count186
\hw@wordcount=\count187
\hw@maxprintline=\count188

(|kpsewhich -var-value=max_print_line))
Class tufte-book Info: Loading the base class `book'

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo
File: bk10.clo 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count189
\c@chapter=\count190
\c@section=\count191
\c@subsection=\count192
\c@subsubsection=\count193
\c@paragraph=\count194
\c@subparagraph=\count195
\c@figure=\count196
\c@table=\count197
\abovecaptionskip=\skip50
\belowcaptionskip=\skip51
\bibindent=\dimen140
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2019/10/25 v3.4 ifpdf legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titlesec.sty
Package: titlesec 2021/07/05 v2.14 Sectioning titles
\ttl@box=\box50
\beforetitleunit=\skip52
\aftertitleunit=\skip53
\ttl@plus=\dimen141
\ttl@minus=\dimen142
\ttl@toksa=\toks18
\titlewidth=\dimen143
\titlewidthlast=\dimen144
\titlewidthfirst=\dimen145
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titletoc.sty
Package: titletoc 2021/07/05 v2.14 TOC entries
\ttl@leftsep=\dimen146
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hypertext links for LaTeX

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty
Package: pdfescape 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty
Package: hycolor 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty
Package: letltxmacro 2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2020-10-07 v3.14 Key value format for package options (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen147
\Hy@linkcounter=\count198
\Hy@pagecounter=\count199

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PD1 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PD1
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref-langpatches.def
File: hyperref-langpatches.def 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref: patches for babel la
nguages
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty
Package: intcalc 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count266

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def
File: puenc.def 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PU ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PU
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `unicode' set `true' on input line 4073.
Package hyperref Info: Option `hyperfootnotes' set `false' on input line 4073.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4192.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4197.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4200.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4207.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4212.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4445.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count267

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip16
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 4804.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen148

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
Package: bitset 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty
Package: bigintcalc 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
))
\Fld@menulength=\count268
\Field@Width=\dimen149
\Fld@charsize=\dimen150
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6076.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6081.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6084.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6091.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6096.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6101.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6106.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6146.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6150.

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty
Package: atbegshi-ltx 2021/01/10 v1.0c Emulation of the original atbegshi
package with kernel methods
)
\Hy@abspage=\count269
\c@Item=\count270
)
Package hyperref Info: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
File: hpdftex.def 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty
Package: atveryend-ltx 2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atvery packag
e
with kernel methods
)
\Fld@listcount=\count271
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count272

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2019/12/05 v1.9 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty
Package: uniquecounter 2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
86.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip54
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ragged2e/ragged2e.sty
Package: ragged2e 2021/02/05 v3.0 ragged2e Package
\CenteringLeftskip=\skip55
\RaggedLeftLeftskip=\skip56
\RaggedRightLeftskip=\skip57
\CenteringRightskip=\skip58
\RaggedLeftRightskip=\skip59
\RaggedRightRightskip=\skip60
\CenteringParfillskip=\skip61
\RaggedLeftParfillskip=\skip62
\RaggedRightParfillskip=\skip63
\JustifyingParfillskip=\skip64
\CenteringParindent=\skip65
\RaggedLeftParindent=\skip66
\RaggedRightParindent=\skip67
\JustifyingParindent=\skip68
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
\Gm@cnth=\count273
\Gm@cntv=\count274
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count275
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen151
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen152
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen153
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen154
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen155
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen156
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen157
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen158
\Gm@dimlist=\toks19
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/changepage/changepage.sty
Package: changepage 2009/10/20 v1.0c check page and change page layout
\c@cp@cntr=\count276
\cp@tempcnt=\count277
)
\@tufte@overhang=\skip69
\@tufte@fullwidth=\skip70
\@tufte@caption@fill=\skip71

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/paralist/paralist.sty
Package: paralist 2017/01/22 v2.7 Extended list environments
\pltopsep=\skip72
\plpartopsep=\skip73
\plitemsep=\skip74
\plparsep=\skip75
\pl@lab=\toks20
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textcase/textcase.sty
Package: textcase 2019/09/14 v1.00 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/letterspace.sty
Package: letterspace 2021/03/14 v2.8c Robust letterspacing (RS)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \lsstyle on input line 346.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \lslig on input line 347.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textls on input line 372.
\MT@outer@kern=\dimen159
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/setspace/setspace.sty
Package: setspace 2011/12/19 v6.7a set line spacing
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Package option `usenames' ignored on input line 216.
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvipsnam.def
File: dvipsnam.def 2016/06/17 v3.0m Driver-dependent file (DPC,SPQR)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/svgnam.def
File: svgnam.def 2016/05/11 v2.12 Predefined colors according to SVG 1.1 (UK)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty
Package: natbib 2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
\bibhang=\skip76
\bibsep=\skip77
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 694.
\c@NAT@ctr=\count278
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/bibentry.sty
Package: bibentry 2007/10/30 1.5 (PWD)
)
No file tufteTry.bbl.
\c@@tufte@num@bibkeys=\count279
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/sauerj/optparams.sty
Package: optparams 2004/08/14 v0.9 multiple optional parameters in macros
)
\@tufte@sidenote@vertical@offset=\skip78

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/placeins/placeins.sty
Package: placeins 2005/04/18  v 2.2
)
\@tufte@margin@floatbox=\box51
\@tufte@figure@box=\box52
\@tufte@caption@box=\box53
\@tufte@caption@vertical@offset=\skip79
\@tufte@float@contents@width=\skip80

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/mathpazo.sty
Package: mathpazo 2020/03/25 PSNFSS-v9.3 Palatino w/ Pazo Math (D.Puga, WaS) 
\symupright=\mathgroup4
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/helvet.sty
Package: helvet 2020/03/25 PSNFSS-v9.3 (WaS) 
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bera/beramono.sty
Package: beramono 2004/01/31 (WaS)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+pplj on input line 1
12.

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/t1pplj.fd
File: t1pplj.fd 2004/09/06 font definitions for T1/pplj.
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
Package: textcomp 2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty
Package: fancyhdr 2021/01/28 v4.0.1 Extensive control of page headers and foote
rs
\f@nch@headwidth=\skip81
\f@nch@O@elh=\skip82
\f@nch@O@erh=\skip83
\f@nch@O@olh=\skip84
\f@nch@O@orh=\skip85
\f@nch@O@elf=\skip86
\f@nch@O@erf=\skip87
\f@nch@O@olf=\skip88
\f@nch@O@orf=\skip89
)
\tufteskipamount=\skip90

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/multicol.sty
Package: multicol 2019/12/09 v1.8y multicolumn formatting (FMi)
\c@tracingmulticols=\count280
\mult@box=\box54
\multicol@leftmargin=\dimen160
\c@unbalance=\count281
\c@collectmore=\count282
\doublecol@number=\count283
\multicoltolerance=\count284
\multicolpretolerance=\count285
\full@width=\dimen161
\page@free=\dimen162
\premulticols=\dimen163
\postmulticols=\dimen164
\multicolsep=\skip91
\multicolbaselineskip=\skip92
\partial@page=\box55
\last@line=\box56
\maxbalancingoverflow=\dimen165
\mult@rightbox=\box57
\mult@grightbox=\box58
\mult@gfirstbox=\box59
\mult@firstbox=\box60
\@tempa=\box61
\@tempa=\box62
\@tempa=\box63
\@tempa=\box64
\@tempa=\box65
\@tempa=\box66
\@tempa=\box67
\@tempa=\box68
\@tempa=\box69
\@tempa=\box70
\@tempa=\box71
\@tempa=\box72
\@tempa=\box73
\@tempa=\box74
\@tempa=\box75
\@tempa=\box76
\@tempa=\box77
\@tempa=\box78
\@tempa=\box79
\@tempa=\box80
\@tempa=\box81
\@tempa=\box82
\@tempa=\box83
\@tempa=\box84
\@tempa=\box85
\@tempa=\box86
\@tempa=\box87
\@tempa=\box88
\@tempa=\box89
\@tempa=\box90
\@tempa=\box91
\@tempa=\box92
\@tempa=\box93
\@tempa=\box94
\@tempa=\box95
\@tempa=\box96
\@tempa=\box97
\c@minrows=\count286
\c@columnbadness=\count287
\c@finalcolumnbadness=\count288
\last@try=\dimen166
\multicolovershoot=\dimen167
\multicolundershoot=\dimen168
\mult@nat@firstbox=\box98
\colbreak@box=\box99
\mc@col@check@num=\count289
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2021-08-04 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count290
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box100
)
No file tufteTry.aux.
\openout1 = `tufteTry.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PU/pdf/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2021-04-02 v2.47 Cross-referencing by name of section

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty
Package: refcount 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.s
ty
Package: gettitlestring 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count291
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 6.
\@outlinefile=\write3
\openout3 = `tufteTry.out'.


*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: letterpaper
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: twoside asymmetric 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(72.26999pt, 312.0pt, 230.02501pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(72.26999pt, 616.0pt, 106.7pt)
* \paperwidth=614.295pt
* \paperheight=794.96999pt
* \textwidth=312.0pt
* \textheight=616.0pt
* \oddsidemargin=0.0pt
* \evensidemargin=0.0pt
* \topmargin=-42.0pt
* \headheight=14.0pt
* \headsep=28.0pt
* \topskip=10.0pt
* \footskip=25.29494pt
* \marginparwidth=144.0pt
* \marginparsep=24.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=9.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidetrue
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

\langwohyphens=\language87
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count292
\scratchdimen=\dimen169
\scratchbox=\box101
\nofMPsegments=\count293
\nofMParguments=\count294
\everyMPshowfont=\toks21
\MPscratchCnt=\count295
\MPscratchDim=\dimen170
\MPnumerator=\count296
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count297
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks22
)
\big@size=\dimen171
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+phv on input line 8.

 (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/t1phv.fd
File: t1phv.fd 2020/03/25 scalable font definitions for T1/phv.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/phv/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 8.99994pt on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/phv/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 16.19989pt on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/phv/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 32.39978pt on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/phv/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 12.59991pt on input line 8.
 [1


{/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]

Package bibentry Warning: You have used \nobibliography* 
(bibentry)                without a following \bibliography.
(bibentry)                You may not be able to run BibTeX.

(./tufteTry.aux)

Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `tufteTry.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck)                or use package `bookmark'.

Package rerunfilecheck Info: Checksums for `tufteTry.out':
(rerunfilecheck)             Before: <no file>
(rerunfilecheck)             After:  D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E;0.
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 11430 strings out of 478542
 169955 string characters out of 5850387
 498504 words of memory out of 5000000
 29170 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 419604 words of font info for 37 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 94i,11n,97p,270b,330s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
{/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}</usr/local/t
exlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/helvetic/uhvr8a.pfb>
Output written on tufteTry.pdf (1 page, 5726 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 19 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 13 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 2 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1537 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: where did you get hold of a texlive 2022/dev? compile the binaries from source?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: The pdflatex-dev in TL2021 is labelled 2022/dev.

Comment: @mk9y: what are the paths to the binaries you have in TeXStudio vs TeXShop?

Comment: How do I check?

Comment: @HerbSchulz as is pdflatex, of that's odd hadn't noticed that.